# Running a DTS Package from VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, dts

I'm trying to run a dts package from vba the code I have at the moment is below, I've blanked out the server and password but I know the password is right.

I tried to put "//" in front of the server just to see if it worked but it didn't (The SQL database is on a separate server to the one i'm trying to run the VBA code on if that matter)

```
Sub ExecutePackage()

    Dim oPKG As DTS.Package, oStep As DTS.Step
    Set oPKG = New DTS.Package

    Dim sServer As String, sUsername As String, sPassword As String
    Dim sPackageName As String, sMessage As String
    Dim lErr As Long, sSource As String, sDesc As String

    ' Set Parameter Values
    sServer = "xxxxxxx"
    sUsername = "xx"
    sPassword = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    sPackageName = "PODs Import"

    ' Load Package
    oPKG.LoadFromSQLServer sServer, sUsername, sPassword, _
        DTSSQLStgFlag_Default, , , , sPackageName

    ' Set Exec on Main Thread
    For Each oStep In oPKG.Steps
        oStep.ExecuteInMainThread = True
    Next

    ' Execute
    oPKG.Execute

    ' Get Status and Error Message
    For Each oStep In oPKG.Steps
        If oStep.ExecutionResult = DTSStepExecResult_Failure Then
            oStep.GetExecutionErrorInfo lErr, sSource, sDesc
            sMessage = sMessage & "Step """ & oStep.Name & _
                """ Failed" & vbCrLf & _
                vbTab & "Error: " & lErr & vbCrLf & _
                vbTab & "Source: " & sSource & vbCrLf & _
                vbTab & "Description: " & sDesc & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        Else
            sMessage = sMessage & "Step """ & oStep.Name & _
                """ Succeeded" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next

    oPKG.UnInitialize

    Set oStep = Nothing
    Set oPKG = Nothing

    ' Display Results
    MsgBox sMessage

End Sub
```

The Error I'm getting
[image]

Edit: 
Found out this is not to do with the VBA code but something to do with it not being local because running it through DTSrun on cmd does not work.